# How to add a text to scan (Existing) PDF with Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, pdf

I tried to add a text to scan PDF using JS.
I want to develop a program that gets a PDF file and edit it by adding Text to it, using a script.
I need a script in Javascript
I read about PDF-LIB and I couldn't found any of describing.
(I also tried to find a script in python,I couldn't found).
If there another way (api in adobe, languages, etc) to achieve my goal, I'll appreciate to learn about it.

Thanks
Eliran